Which is the cause and which one is the effect between the shear stress and velocity gradient in a fluid flow?
Take a Newtonian fluid flow between two parallel plates, one at rest and one at constant velocity, then there will be a linear velocity gradient between those two plates. Is it due to the no-slip condition that the velocity gradient is formed?
Or, is it due to shear stresses between fluid layer that causes the velocity gradient?
If the former claim is right, then logically I can say that even for viscous real fluid, if there is a perfect slip at the bottom layer, then there would be no velocity gradient and consequently no shear stresses between the fluid layers according to Newton's law of viscosity. So which is true and which causes what?
Could someone please provide me with related papers that address my doubt?

The primary reason is the relative motion of the walls and fluid viscosity. If you work with a viscous fluid, both no-slip condition at solid wall is satisfied and viscosity introduces shear stresses in the flow.
Let's describe the transient behavior of the system, considering a  channel whose height $H$ is small enough to have small enough Reynolds number $Re = \frac{U H}{\nu}$, to have a viscosity-dominated system and avoid complex dynamics. Let's take a channel that is long enough to neglect the effects of extreme sections: if these assumptions hold, it's reasonable to expect the dimension $x$ along the channel as a homogeneous direction, so that problem is independent from coordinate $x$.

the system start from fluid and walls at rest,

(as an example) the upper wall is instantaneously moved at velocity $U$ (taken as the characteristic velocity in the Reynolds number); no-slip boundary conditions hold at wall, so the solid wall drag the "first layer" of fluid with it

shear stress drags the neighboring fluid layers; as time increases, further layers are driven by the shear stress of neighboring layers: to be more specific, the problem is a diffusion problem of the $x$-component of the velocity field $u(y,t)$
$$\begin{cases}
\frac{\partial u}{\partial t} - \nu \frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial y^2} = 0 \\
u(y,0) = 0 \\
u(H,t) = U \\
u(0,t) = 0
\end{cases}$$
with and the kinematic viscosity $\nu$ as diffusion coefficient,  assuming no-slip boundary conditions hold at the lower wall as well

this system has a steady solution $\overline{u}(y)$, so that $\frac{\partial u}{\partial t} = 0$; this solution is reached at the end of the transient
and is the linear velocity profile satisfying the steady problem
$$\begin{cases}
 \frac{\partial^2 \overline{u}}{\partial y^2} = 0 \\
\overline{u}(H) = U \\
\overline{u}(0) = 0
\end{cases}$$
and thus $u(y) = U \frac{y}{H}$.


